# Printing number of columns in for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have probably the dumbest question, so bear with me. I want to understand how the logic of for loop in R.

```
  df = matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),3,3) #create a 3x3 matrix

  for ( i in 1:ncol(df)){
       print(i)
   }

#  [1] 1
#  [1] 2
#  [1] 3
```

Why is it only printing the first column results, shouldn't it print all the columns element as followings:

```
#  [1] 1 
#  [1] 2
#  [1] 3
#  [2] 4 
#  [2] 5
#  [2] 6
#  [3] 7 
#  [3] 8
#  [3] 9
```

Thanks for your help and please keep your answers at a dummy level.

Comment: I think you intended to do this: `matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), nrow=3, ncol=3)`

Comment: In your for loop, all you are printing is your variable `i` try `print(df[,i])` which accesses the columns of the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apart from the typo... you should know that `ncol(df) = 3`, right? So when you use a loop:

```
for ( i in 1:ncol(df))
```

`i` will only be 1, 2, 3.

Are you... puzzled with the `[1]`?? That signals the first line of `print`, and does not mean the first column of the matrix. Maybe you should try a more random matrix:

```
df <- matrix(runif(9), 3, 3)
```

then you will not associate the printed number with matrix elements.